# Build a binary wheel and a source tarball

Tags: github-actions, pypi, python-wheel

I am trying to use an action with GitHub to release automatically in pypi, when I am releasing in GitHub. It works fine, however I cannot find the wheel and the source tarball in the dist folder, but the workflow do upload them in pypi.

I am using an .yml file according to [this](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/publishing-package-distribution-releases-using-github-actions-ci-cd-workflows/):

```
name: publish on testpypi

on: 
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  build-n-publish:
    name: publish on testpypi
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install pypa/build
      run: >-
        python -m
        pip install
        build
        --user
    - name: Build a binary wheel and a source tarball
      run: >-
        python -m
        build
        --sdist
        --wheel
        --outdir dist/
    - name: Publish distribution to Test PyPI
      uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@release/v1
      with:
        password: ${{ secrets.PYPI_API_TOKEN }}
        packages_dir: dist/
        repository_url: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
```

At the line --outdir dist/ it should store both files (wheel and source tarball) in the folder dist. The GitHub .log gives

> Successfully built example_package_grigorisha-0.1.8.tar.gz and example_package_grigorisha-0.1.8-py3-none-any.whl

and both files were uploaded successfully to pypi, but I cannot find the data in the folder /dist. My suggestion is, that a folder is created somewhere else, where I cannot find it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you expect to find the `dist` folder?

Comment: I have expected it in my github repository folder.

Comment: Github Actions do not automagically modify the repository. Anything you want to see in the repo must be added, committed and pushed back; do not forget the push re-triggers the action(s), prevent it with `[skip ci]` command in the commit message. Without commit/push all files reside on the virtual machine that run the action, preserved for some time for inspection and then garbage collected.

Comment: I didnt mean the repository but the local folder of the github project. However, I cannot find where these data are stored.

Comment: There're no local folders, only repository directories/files. Directories/files created by Github Actions are stored on the virtual machines that run the action(s) and are not accessible after the run have finished. To access them after all actions have finished either save them as [artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts) or store them somewhere outside of Actions.